# How to report on a table based on variable in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How do you list the details of any table (or all the tables) based on user selection? For example I want to have a dataset that contains the query:

```
SELECT * FROM @TableName
```

And then `@TableName` will get the list of tables from sys.tables. My database version is SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate your `@TableName` parameter you can use:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables
```

Then your Dataset's Sql Statement can be an expression:

```
="SELECT * FROM " & Parameters!TableName.Value
```

However, this won't be especially useful. While the Sql Statement will execute, what are the field names going to be? This would, I imagine, be different for every table in your database. When the Sql Statement is an expression the field names aren't automatically populated and you have to add them manually. Then you have to go about mapping these fields to your table columns somehow.

So while you can theoretically do what you want to do, you can't practically use the results.

So no, you can't have one generic report for every table in your database (unless the tables for some reason have exactly the same structure).